LongPressGesture in RealityView for visionOS
I'm trying to make a multi stage long press gesture where it switches between pressing, released, or inactive to execute certain action depending on the states appropriately.
However, I have trouble changing the gesture state of the LongPressState. The updating closure does not seem to be called.
Below is the code I have currently.
enum LongPressState {
    case inactive
    case pressing
    case released
}

@GestureState private var longPressState: LongPressState = .inactive
private let longPressDuration: Double = 1.0
private let longPressDistance: CGFloat = 50.0

var longPress: some Gesture {
    LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: longPressDuration, maximumDistance: longPressDistance)
        .targetedToAnyEntity()
        .updating($longPressState) { value, gestureState, transaction in
            print("Updating")
            gestureState = .pressing
        }
        .onEnded { value in
            print(longPressState)
            switch longPressState {
                case .inactive:
                    print("Inactive stage")
                case .pressing:
                    print("Pressing stage")
                case .released:
                    print("Released stage")
            }
        }
}

var body: some View {
    RealityView { content in
        ...
    }
    .gesture(longPress)
}



For entity targeting to work on a given RealityKit entity, the entity must have both a CollisionComponent and an InputTargetComponent

var body: some View {
    RealityView { content in
        let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.1), materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: .white, isMetallic: true)])
        entity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
        entity.components.set(InputTargetComponent())
        content.add(entity)
    }
    .gesture(longPress)
}

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10203

Hello, thank you for answering. The entity already has the 2 components you mentioned. the onEnded closure works, but not the updating closure. I tested the code here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/composing-swiftui-gestures, it works with UI elements, but does not work with Entity it seems.

@ViTiet there is something wrong with your model then. If you change the body to the code I provided you will see a cube and long press will work
